# Unable to install libgnutls-dev on new 16.04LTS machine

Tags: 16.04, apt

Brand new installed system 16.04LTS, only installed Xenial packages.

`sudo apt install libgnutls-dev`

results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls30 (= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgnutlsxx28 (= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nettle-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libtasn1-6-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libp11-kit-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libidn11-dev (>= 1.31) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The error message (xxx is there but xxxx+version is to be installed) makes no sense whatsoever. There is nothing to be installed other than the packages listed.

`sudo apt install -f` results in nada:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`apt-cache policy libgnutls-dev`

gives

```
libgnutls-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.4.10-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.4.10-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `apt-cache policy libgnutls-dev` to it.

Comment: added output as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of `libgnutls-dev` on xenial is `3.4.10-4ubuntu1.4`.

It seems that you disabled `xenial-updates` repository.

- On desktop open *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`), go to *Updates* tab and check `xenial-security` and `xenial-updates`.
- On server you should have the following line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

  ```
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  ```

And try to install it again.