# "libgnutls-dev has no installation candidate" error while installing Ubuntu as a DC in a Windows server domain

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, gnutls

I am trying to install Ubuntu (the latest) as a AD-Server in a test Windows server domain. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf7Hk8qWt1Q) but it is somewhat old.

When arriving at minute 14, I am lost. I need to install the following (don't know why):

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libgnutls-dev libreadline-dev python-dev python-dnspython gdb pkg-config libpopt-dev libldap2-dev dnsutils libbsd-dev attr krb5-user docbook-xsl libcups2-dev libpam0g-dev ntp -y
```

but it is giving me the following error:

```
libgnutls-dev has no installation candidate
```

So I tried [Unable to install libgnutls-dev on new 16.04LTS machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001262/unable-to-install-libgnutls-dev-on-new-16-04lts-machine) but with no luck.

Anyone who can help me with this what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include your Ubuntu release? `libgnutls-dev` certainly [exists in Xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgnutls-dev) but it was [renamed to `libgnutls28-dev` in Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgnutls28-dev).

Comment: On another note, all currently supported Ubuntu releases already include a version of Samba that is more recent than the upstream version at the time of creation of the linked tutorial video, so you don't need to install it from source. A simple installation of the package `samba` should be enough. See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-dc.html for more.

Answer (score 7):

Looking into this, I found https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gnutls28

Change the package to `libgnutls28-dev`, so your command would be

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libgnutls28-dev libreadline-dev python-dev python-dnspython gdb pkg-config libpopt-dev libldap2-dev dnsutils libbsd-dev attr krb5-user docbook-xsl libcups2-dev libpam0g-dev ntp
```

Comment: USE libgnutls28-dev