# Package 'emacs26' has no installation candidate

Tags: emacs

I get this error message when trying to install emacs.

[image]

I have run upgrade and update multiple times. The instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058694/libgnutls-dev-has-no-installation-candidate-error-while-installing-ubuntu-as-a#comment1732060_1058694) come up when searching my error, but are either irrelevant or do not work. If I try 27 or 28, the error is "unable to locate package", which is even worse.

OS: Windows 10

Ubuntu version: 20.04.1

I've tried writing just "emacs" before, but this gives me the minimalistic version of emacs:

[image]

Comment: What leads you to believe `emacs26` is the right package name? Are you following an installation guide somewhere which may be wrong or outdated? You didn't specify what release of Ubuntu you're running, but `sudo apt install emacs` should work.

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details, but a quick `rmadison emacs` tells me v.26 is available for some releases, but v.27 is  also for my release... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=emacs&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all   Please provide OS & release details for package queries.

Comment: @guiverc Updated with OS and version number. If I use that command, I get the wrong version of emacs, see the new image.

Comment: @karel No, I got the message "universe distribution component is already enabled for all sources."