# E: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-dev

Tags: gtk, gtk-2

I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgtk2.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk2.0-dev'
```

In trying to install:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

I have:

```
Linux 0803156b7532 4.15.0-15-generic #16~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 12:19:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also, I get (as a root):

```
apt-get update
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
Reading package lists...
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
```

Running the following commands in a remote docker, I get these errors:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&  apt-get update && apt-get install libglib2.0-0
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
Reading package lists...
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
```

Running the following set of commands:

```
echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&  apt-get update && apt-get install libglib2.0-0
```

I get:

```
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
Reading package lists...
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:26 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:26 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
E: setgroups 65534 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setegid 65534 failed - setegid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: seteuid 104 failed - seteuid (1: Operation not permitted)
E: setgroups 0 failed - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method gave invalid 400 URI Failure message: Failed to setgroups - setgroups (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (112)
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:26 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:26 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
```

result of `id` on the Docker is:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Did you have any error on last `sudo apt-get update`? Please also add output of `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-dev` to the question.

Comment: I updated my answer. I do not see anything for the policy command

Comment: Then try `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` followed by `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libglib2.0-0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libglib2.0-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libglib2.0-0'

Comment: @N0rbert did what you mentioned and updated my question

Comment: Make sure you have all necessary software sources enabled (as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001297/66509)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80889/discussion-between-mona-jalal-and-n0rbert).

Comment: Are you using docker with user namespaces? If so, please paste the contents of `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` from your host environment. Also, please start a shell in docker and paste the result of this command of `/proc/$$/setgroups`.